# OSX : absolute desktop file path ? (including /Volumes)

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, filepath, automator

When I try to retrieve the path of a file on my desktop, I get :

```
/Users/MyName/Desktop/file.txt
```

But I need the full path (to feed a bash script):

```
/Volumes/MyDrive/Users/MyName/Desktop/file.txt
```

I spent quite some time searching for a solution, but couldn't find any.
I'm open to anything that can be run through Automator, bash or applescript.

It makes me crazy because if I simply drop my file.txt in Coda, it will output the full absolute path I want, right away, whereas Terminal won't.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you just manually add '/Volumes/MyDrive/' to the start of your string?

Comment: Is your home directory not on the boot column? Otherwise, `/Volumes/MyDrive` is just a symlink to `/` anyway. If Terminal isn't giving you path rooted in `/Volumes`, `/Users/...` should work fine in a bash script.

Comment: Thanks for the help !
My problem is that I use the file path to mount a volume (using AFP). So I need to invoke afp://192.168.1.100/Volumes/MyDrive/Users/file.txt. Any tricks in the hat for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to find which volume under `/Volumes` is equivalent to `/`, yes?  That's easy - just look for the symlink to /.

```
for vol in /Volumes/*; do 
  if [ "$(readlink "$vol")" = / ]; then 
    root_vol=$vol
  fi
done
```

Then you can do

```
echo "$root_vol$HOME/Desktop/file.txt"
```

or whatever.

Comment: Thanks a million ! Very simple and functional :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might need it :
if you're running an OSX Automator workflow/application/service and needs an absolute path to your input file, simply add a "Run shell script" action, set the input "as arguments" and use the following :

---

```
#!/bin/bash

## Check if the input is an absolute path including the volume name
if [[ "$1" = /Volumes/* ]]
    ## If TRUE, the path is already correct
    then
        echo "$1"

    ## If FALSE, needs fixing
    else
        ## Resolve the volume name
        ## by looping through all the volumes to find the one symlinked to "/"
        for vol in /Volumes/*
            do 
                if [ "$(readlink "$vol")" = / ]
                    then root_vol=$vol
                fi
            done
        ## Pass the path back to Automator for further use
        echo "$root_vol$1"
fi
```

---